# Bigcommerce Handlebars if one of / if x or y

Tags: mustache, bigcommerce

Is there a way with the helpers provided to check if object is one of several strings, like the following:

```
{{#or (page_type '===' 'blog') (page_type '===' 'blog_post')}}
```

Happy to use some other transformation to get at the same result, but I haven't found a way. Frustrating to have to repeat code blocks to achieve this result.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a late answer but you can use this:

```
{{#or (if page_type '===' 'blog') (if page_type '===' 'blog_post')}}
```